# UINavigationBar default color

Tags: iphone, ipad, user-interface, colors, uinavigationbar

I'm just wondering what UINavigationBar's  default color is (on the iPhone).

I can't find it anywhere, and calling `CGColorGetComponents()` on `navigationBar.tintColor.CGColorRef` has no effect.

For example, if I programmatically set the color to, let's say, red, how do I get it back to normal?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: do you need it dynamically or just you want to get the colors?

Comment: I just want to be able to restore it after programmatically setting the color.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To get the default look, you'd set the `tintColor` to `nil`.

It's not possible to set it to an instance of `UIColor` and have it look completely the same as in the default style, because the button colors are slightly different in the default look. For example, `UIBarButtonItem`s with 'Done' button style have a different color than when you explicitly set a tint color  that would otherwise resemble the default color of the bar itself.

Also note that the default tint color is different on iPad (and might change in future versions of iOS).

Answer (score 0):

The right way is setting the `tintColor` to `nil`. I had a situation in which that was not wished for for different reasons and applying the color was needed. In case someone runs into that, I created a color asset with colours #121212 and in light mode #F7F7F7

Light mode:

```
#colorLiteral(red: 0.9763854146, green: 0.9765252471, blue: 0.9763546586, alpha: 1)`
```

Dark mode:

```
#colorLiteral(red: 0.071, green: 0.071, blue: 0.071, alpha: 1)
```

But 100% the right way is what @omz describes.