# Retaining the UIBarButtonItem blue "done" tint with a custom navigationBar tintColor

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

As noted here and elsewhere: [edit/done button, change done button background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673722/edit-done-button-change-done-button-background-color)

If you custom tint your `navigationBar` using `navigationBar.tintColor`, you lose the default custom blue appearance of a `UIBarButtonItemStyleDone` button. I need a "Next" button that retains this custom blue appearance, but need to custom tint my `navigationBar`.

As noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4704198/675943

If you manually set the RGB of the `UIBarButtonItem` it looks different from the system default.

Is there any way for me to retain the system default "Next" button blue-style appearance with a tinted navBar? Setting `tintColor` to `nil` as mentioned in the above link doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is, you can create bar button item with custom view

- (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView

Pass UIButton as custom view. Set targrt & action to UIButton and image which looks like default blue appearance of a UIBarButtonItemStyleDone.